# TBB need condition_variable for task synchronization

Tags: task, tbb, condition-variable

I'm using tbb for some project, and i'm forced to use tbb tasks.

My program has N tasks, who are interact.

Pseudo code goes like this:

```
class Task;

Task* t[N];

class Task {
    startTask(Task &t) {
        t.notify();
    }
    execute() {
        while(!end){
            if(some condition 1)
                wait();

            for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
                if(some condition 2)
                    startTask(*t[i]);

            if(some condition 3)
                end = true;
        }
    }
};
```

**N >> cores**

If I use condition_variable for this job, then thread stop and thread stops all tasks.
Is there some method what I can use to make my job done?

I've trying to use recycle, but only CORE_NUMBER task's working, and other N-CORE_NUMBER tasks never start to execute.

Best regards,

Goran

Answer (score 4):

(Disclaimer: I work for Intel and on Intel® Threading Building Blocks)

Yes, TBB tasks are non-preemptive and they are scheduled on to a fixed number of worker threads.  So if you have tasks on all of the worker threads and all of these tasks are waiting, then you will deadlock.  No other task can be scheduled to wake up the others, since all worker threads are busy executing (blocked) tasks.

A few things that I can think of:

1. Can you restructure your application so that a task is spawned only when the condition it will wait on is satisfied?   Your pseudo-code seems to indicate that you spawn the task and then it checks whether it can proceed.  Instead of blocking in the task, can you only schedule the task when it is able to complete?
2. If you know the order in which the tasks are allowed to execute, you might create a graph of tasks ( http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/tbb_sa/help/hh_goto.htm#tbb_userguide/General_Acyclic_Graphs_of_Tasks.htm ).
3. You can use the flow graph to implement streaming and reactive applications in TBB.  Is it possible to implement it as a flow graph? ( http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/the-intel-threading-building-blocks-flow/231900177 )

Can you provide any more details on what the conditions look like?  Your pseudo-code is very abstract, so my suggestions might be way off the mark…

Comment: My project can be implemented as a flow graph, but specification don't allow it. I need to simulate wireless sensor network and to discovery shortest path beetween all of them, BUT one sensor must be one task, and they must be syncd by some mailbox(every sensor has his own mailbox). That's why I need conditions. When mailbox is empty that doesn't say that task is done, but say that task must wait until mailbox isn't empty. I can done that project as simple recursion (like some of fibonacci tutorials), but specification says first: 1 sensor - 1 task, second: sync by mailbox.

Best regards,Goran

Comment: Then, the specification is where the problem lies; perhaps it was written without enough knowledge of TBB tasks. A sensor is something with a significant duration of life, processes many events that it needs to wait on. A TBB task, on the other hand, is expected to be a rather short chunk of computation, independent of other chunks (in the sense that when a task is submitted to TBB for execution, its dependencies are satisfied already). You will not be able to implement these requirements.